# How to subtract 30 minutes from a timeinterval in Swift?

Tags: swift, datepicker, nstimeinterval

I have made an App with a datePicker and 2 buttons - "Check in" and "Check out". I did the calculation between the two timestamps in hours and minutes.
Now I want to subtract 30 minutes from that time interval, IF the "Check in" is before 12:00.

### This is my code so far:

```
var start = Date()

var end = Date()

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var timeWheel: UIDatePicker!
@IBOutlet weak var workLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func checkIn(_ sender: Any) {
    start = timeWheel.date
    workLabel.text = ""
}

@IBAction func checkOut(_ sender: Any) {
    end = timeWheel.date
    let difference = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: start, to: end)
    workLabel.text = "\(difference.hour ?? 0) timer og \(difference.minute ?? 0) minutter"
}
}
```

---

Got any suggestions ?

Comment: Didn't understand the question. Kindly elaborate with an example.

Comment: I need to subtract 30 minutes from the time difference, if "checkIn" is before 12:00 AM - so if the checkIn is 8:00 and checkOut is 15:00 - the time difference should be 6 hours and 30 minutes (lunch break subtracted from work time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before calculating the difference get the `hour` component of `start` and check if it's less than 12. If yes subtract the 30 minutes and then do the math

```
@IBAction func checkOut(_ sender: Any) {
    end = timeWheel.date
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let startHour = calendar.component(.hour, from: start)
    let startDate = startHour < 12 ? calendar.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 30, to: start)! : start
    let difference = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: startDate, to: end)
    workLabel.text = "\(difference.hour!) timer og \(difference.minute!) minutter"
}
```

Forces unwrapping the components is perfectly fine as both components were clearly requested.

Comment: but if I set the checkin to 8:00 and the checkOut to 15:15 the result is 7 hours 45 minutes - which is not quiet right :(

Comment: 8:00 - 0:30 is 7:30 and 15:15 - 7:30 is 7:45

Comment: I found the solution !
By adding the 30 minutes to start - it gives the right result
So from 8:00 to 15:00 it gives me 6 hours and 30 minutes,
but from 13:00 to 15:00 gives me 2 hours and 0 minutes
Thank you :)

Comment: My bad, I misread *subtract from start date* You have to **add** the 30 minutes to the start date. I updated the answer.

Comment: are you able to explain the this line: " let startDate = startHour < 12 ? calendar.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 30, to: start)! : start " , so that I may explain it to others ?

Comment: @JimmiHeegaard That's the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). If the condition `startHour < 12` is true the code between `?` and `:` is executed otherwise the code after  `:`